# fiddler not capturing any browser traffic (Not IE, FF, or CHROME)

Tags: browser, proxy, fiddler

I'm not getting traffic from any browser (or any app).  Two things that are probably contributing:

1)  I'm in the workplace and we are running a corporate proxy
2)  the Win INET Lan Settings are locked down

Running Win7 64 Fiddler 4.5.1.0
What I've tried:
Default install of fiddler
IE 11 with no add-ons.
Running fiddler as Administrator
Changing group policy for "Make proxy setting per machine" to DISABLED

No errors/warning messages from Fiddler
No filters being used, filter box unchecked
The LOG tab is empty
Filter troubleshooting enabled shows no activity
http://localhost.fiddler:8888/ returns Unknown Host
http://127.0.0.1:8888/ returns a 200

Is fiddler compatible with corporate proxies?  thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a valid SO question, as it's not related to programming.

Comment: I disagree.  I know many programmers.  I would say a majority of client-side programmers use tools like fiddler.  According to the SO help page, appropriate topics include "software tools commonly used by programmers".  The Fiddler web page defines the tool as a "debugging proxy".  Debugging is a common task performed by programmers.

Answer (score 3):

> Is fiddler compatible with corporate proxies?

Of course. Fiddler was developed behind a corporate proxy (Microsoft's) for nine years.

You've identified the source of your problem: "2)" -- the system proxy settings are locked down.

The described workarounds of setting the Group Policy or running Fiddler at Admin do work in every case I've ever seen, but require that you have the appropriate permissions and execute these steps correctly.

Having said that, both Firefox and Chrome can be configured to use proxy settings different than the system's proxy settings; Firefox’s proxy settings are found by opening its **Tools** menu, clicking the **Options** item, and opening the **Advanced** settings. Select the **Network** tab. At the top of the tab, click the **Settings**… button to the right of **Configure how Firefox connects to the Internet**. Set the HTTP and HTTPS proxies to 127.0.0.1:8888 [image: Firefox Proxy settings].

For Chrome, launch it via: `chrome --proxy-server=http://127.0.0.1:8888`.